# Check page and add class

Tags: jquery, css

First of all need to check currently opened page and after that to add some classes. This I would like to solve using only jQuery.

I tried this and checking page works fine, instead of `$('.about_apartment').addClass('none');}`
I've added `alert("Works fine");`
 and I became convinced that checking page works fine.

But when I tried to add my necessary code it's not working in this case, I just can not add class `none`:

There is code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("?apartmentpage.html") > -1) {
        $('.about_apartment').addClass('none');
    }
});
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: Also: Is the `?` in your `indexOf` call really correct? It seems like there should be a `/` there.

Comment: what window.location.href return

Comment: the element with `.about_apartment` is static or dynamically added?

Comment: try removing `?` from the statement `window.location.href.indexOf("?apartmentpage.html")`

Comment: DanielH 
static added

DanielDiekmeier
Works fine with ?, I've checked using alert

Answer (score 1):

By itself your code works, and since you haven't posted any other code.  I'll just demonstrate with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0qac7m8/)

I used your same code but added a check before and after adding the class to verify it works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("fiddle") > -1) {

    //Check to see if "none" class exsists
    alert($(".none")[0]);

    $('.about_apartment').addClass('none');

    //Check for "none" class again.
    alert($(".none")[0]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but look right now work propertly to addclass for static element. If I try for dinamically element to add class not working?

Comment: Are you also adding the class dynamically with jQuery?

Comment: Thats plugin for booking https://www.bookingsync.com/ . And he generate some elements and I want for certain element to remove active class.
https://www.bookingsync.com/api/v2/js/booknow.js

Maybe it;s working currently, because I think I have problem with caching site and after 10 minutes show changes on preview